# what is the cleaner way to write large strings in react website?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I need to render large text in some places and sometimes small descriptions on my website.
The text is not in English language what makes left-right vs right-left to be really annoying.

Moreover, the componenet containing the text became very large and hard to maintain.
I'm not a pro yet but i'm sure there is a best practice for my question.

Currently, my way to solve the large text is to render small components with the text only. (ofc I can create another api that includes the desired text but not in this case. I want to seek other way)

//folder contain MainCompoenent.jsx and TextComponenet.jsx

MainCompoenent:

```
import React from "react";
import TextComponenet from "./TextComponenet.jsx"


const MainCompoenent= () => {
  return <div>
         <ManyHtmlTagsandExtraLogic>
         <TextComponenet />
         </ManyHtmlTagsandExtraLogic>
</div>;
};

export default MainCompoenent;
```

TextComponenet:

```
import React from "react";
const text = `lorem but not in English language * 1000 `;

const TextComponenet= () => {
  return <div>{text}</div>;
};

export default TextComponenet;
```

Comment: So what's wrong with current approach? You can use translation mechanism to move all these strings into some external source, like Json file or even third party tool

Comment: Maybe you can use react-markdown. Here's a link to the repo https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown

Comment: @ Justinas , maybe it can work for me. in my componenet i will write keys of my strings in english and the value will be in other langughe, thanks. i think this is the best practice for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you meant this with "I can create another API", but in my opinion, best way to handle this is have a component similar to the one you created, TextComponent, but make it reusable by using props.

Then, for an example, you can create one separate file called i.e. "alltexts.js", where you can either create (and export) one JSON object with all the texts that you need, or you can create a separate variable for each of your texts and export them.
Then on the parent component that calls the text component, you can import the "alltexts.js", and pass the specific text as props to the TextComponent like

```
<TextComponent text={myText} />
```

Comment: Yea om doing so but in this case the design in each place is very different , its not only text.  i start to understand that not the large text is the problem as the different language that make text align to be very hard to maintain

Comment: @Bennyh961 you could make CSS specifications also changeable with props. For example, make a prop boolean which is true/false for Left-to-right text. And then have a css style rule based on it. So when you call the text component, you tell it how to behave based on text you gave it.  This also works for alignment. If you can specify the design differences, maybe I can come up with a more specific solution.